# Find entities with missing attributes in Datomic

Tags: missing-data, datomic

If I have the following [Datomic](http://www.datomic.com) database:

```
{ :fred :age 42 }
{ :fred :likes :pizza }
{ :sally :age 42 }
```

How do I query for both entities (`:fred` and `:sally`), getting back the attribute `:likes :pizza` for `:fred` and an empty value for `:sally`?

The query

```
[:find ?n ?a ?l
 :where [?n :age ?a]
        [?n :likes ?l]]
```

only returns `:fred 42 :pizza`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Datomic has recently been updated with a few expression functions available to you in Datomic queries. One of these functions is called `get-else` and it lets you provide a default return value if an attribute doesn't exist on an entity, much like how `clojure.core/get` will return an option third param if the key isn't found.

So using your own example, you would only need to change it like so:

`[:find ?n ?a ?l
 :where [?n :age ?a]
        [(get-else $ ?n :likes false) ?l]`

Unfortunately you can't actually make `nil` a "default" value since it's not a valid Datomic data type, and Datomic will carp if you try, but false should get you where you're going as well.

Comment: This is not the correct answer any longer. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35741268/24172

Answer (score 12):

You can also try the "missing?" fn.

Have a look on this:

http://docs.datomic.com/query.html#missing

Answer (score 6):

Getting back a set of entities which may or may not have particular attributes asserted is analogous to a LEFT JOIN in a relational database.

The approach in datomic is to do two steps: first query for the entities and then navigate from there to get the attribute values or `nil` if the attribute is not asserted for a given entity.

See the mailing list post [How do you do a left join in Datomic?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/datomic/F8Loy1KSysM) with its accompanying [gist](https://gist.github.com/stuarthalloway/2948756#file-datomic-news-updates-L210) for an example.

Comment: Actually, I believe `get-else` is the correct approach in this case. It's a single query rather than two steps. As an FYI another similar built in functions is `missing?`.